# Get parameter from URL Scheme - Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme, viewdidload, info.plist

I've made a URL scheme in the `Info.plist` to call my app, but the URL also parses a string of data which I need to read.

After looking around for a little while I've found - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2301787&seqNum=2

with the following code

```
var scheme: String!
var path: String!

var query: String!

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {

  scheme = url.scheme
  path = url.path
  query = url.query

  return true
}
```

supposedly the function is called whenever I call the app through a URL, the function however is never called, and I can't imagine that I would have to put the function in the `viewDidLoad`, if I did put it in the `viewDidLoad` it would be called everytime the app started.

Am I wrong im presuming that - the function doesn't need to be called in the `viewDidLoad` or is there a better way to get data from a URL scheme using the Info.plist to create the scheme

Comment: this method is deprecated try to use - application:openURL:options:

Comment: I have written a step-by-step walkthrough of registering URL schemes (but in Objective-C), and this shows how to get the "application" function to get launched:  http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/XCode/CustomURLs.htm

Comment: @Johnykutty alright, I'll implement that instead & update my question when I've done so, thank you :)

Comment: @Johnykutty I've edittd my question, something like that?

Comment: @Johnykutty the application:openURL:options didn't work either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var scheme: String!
var path: String!

var query: String!

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {

  scheme = url.scheme
  path = url.path
  query = url.query

  return true
}
```

need to be in AppDelegate.Swift you can then access it in the viewcontroller by doing -

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate;
```

and you can then call a variable by doing -

```
var something = pathScheme.appDelegate;
```

Comment: Nice work! Thanks! I was struggling with the same problem :D